# How to remove internal padding on panda area plot

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I'm using google collab to generate some graphs, and this one used to fill 100% of the internal area, but today it haves an internal padding, how can I fix this?

```
year = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018']
memory_related = [70, 75, 77, 82, 79, 69, 65, 70, 83, 70, 70, 78, 67]
non_memory_related = [100-x for x in memory_related]
cve_reported_problems = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Year': year,
     'Memory related issues': memory_related,
     'Other issues': non_memory_related
    })
cve_reported_problems.plot.area(x='Year', figsize=(12, 4)).get_figure().savefig('ramissues.pdf')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
plot = cve_reported_problems.plot.area(x='Year', figsize=(12, 4))
plot.autoscale(tight=True)
plot.get_figure().savefig('ramissues.pdf')
```

Comment: It worked, many thanks. Where did you find the documentation for this? Both https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html and https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html doesn't mention "tight" as a valid parameter

Comment: @VictorPanisa https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.autoscale.html